# Hexagon tesselations

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

> A configuration is made of congruent regular hexagons,where each
>   hexagon shares a side with another hexagon. What is the largest
>   integer $k$, such that the figure cannot have $k$ vertices ? For
>   example this figure has $13$ vertices.[image]

That's what I've been able to do so far.

- A hexagon built on one hexagon adds up $4$ vertices to the configuration.
- A hexagon between two hexagons adds up $3$ vertices.
- A hexagon between $3$ hexagons adds up $2$ vertices
- A hexagon between $4$ hexagons adds $1$ vertice
- A hexagon between $5$ hexagons adds $0$ vertices
- A hexagon between $6$ hexagons adds $0$ vertices

Now it's clear that what ever number of vertices I have, I get it through the above combinations.

However I don't know what I have to do now.

It seems to me that I can add an infinite number of hexagons constructed one on the other  and have an infinite number of vertices...

Can you guys help ?

Comment: I'm quite sure I counted 13.

Comment: Are you not counting the same vertice twice ?

Comment: I think the author intended to include internal vertices.

Comment: Then I have had it wrong all the time.I edit

Comment: I try to make some efforts on my own back again.Then if I will have problems I will post the question again.(I delete the question for now)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making a chain of $\geq2$ hexagons you can realize all $k$ of the form $k=10+4m$, $m\geq0$. Starting with your figure and attaching a chain of hexagons you can realize all $k=13+4m$ vertices, and starting with a blob of $4$, resp. $5$, hexagons one shows that all $k$ of the form $k=16+4m$ or $k=19+4m$, $m\geq0$, can be realized in this way. Note that $10$, $13$, $16$, $19$ represent all four remainders modulo $4$. Given that, we can realize all of
$$10,13,14,16,17,18,19, 20,21,22,23,24,\ldots\ .$$

Therefore it seems that the largest non-realizable $k$ is $19-4=15$. In order to make sure that $k=15$ cannot be realized an impossibility proof is required. Such proofs are notoriously difficult.

Any configuration can be built up one for one, so that it remains connected all the time. Start with two hexagons glued together, making $10$ vertices. Then show that you can never reach $15$ vertices using your list of simple principles.

Comment: Bear with me,while I understand that $15$ is not realizable I can't understand how that result is derived. $19-4 =15$ seems completely random for me,as it could have been $22-4$ or $25-4$  etc...(I know these numbers are constructible).Forgive me if I am being annoying but I am just trying to learn.

Comment: Although impossibility proofs are hard in general, in this case there are only a few configurations to check (any configuration of 4 hexagons has at least 16 vertices).